# Is there situation when using constants instead of literal values in the code will make the contract deploy more expensive?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, deployed-bytecode

I was reading a smart contract code in solidity and I found some magic numbers (literal values as function arguments or in some expressions).
My first impulse was refactor it to use named constants but a team colleague rised this question. May this refactoring turn the contract deployment more expensive?

I took a look at solidity style guide page but I didn't find an answer.

Any help about it would be great!

Thanks in advance,
Cláudio.

Comment: Constant are inlined in the code, there's no special place to store them. In my tests I wasn't able to find a pattern, sometimes it was better to use constants, and other it was better using them directly.